# Using sbt-git-plugin in Play! framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm trying to use Git commands in Play! console directly. So, I found the [sbt-git-plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git-plugin) and tried to use it. To do this, I followed the instructions explained in the above link.

(including

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("scalasbt", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "jgit-repo" at "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven"

addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-git-plugin" % "0.4")
```

to project/plugins.sbt file.)

However, my Play! console is saying that it cannot find 'org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main'. Is there anything that I have to check or do? Please, let me know that how I can apply this SBT plugin in Play framework.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the JGit Maven repository is down (404 from http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven/).

You should try with an alternate repository, such as http://eclipse.ialto.org/jgit/maven/repository/ :

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("scalasbt", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "jgit-repo" at "http://eclipse.ialto.org/jgit/maven/repository/"

addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-git-plugin" % "0.4")
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.. In my play-2.0.2 folder(repository/cache), there are jars of jGit. However, it looks like my play-2.0.2 console cannot find any classpath or something..

Comment: please remove the files from your cache and retry.